# Как из класса xpath вытащить что то одно

Tags: html, xpath

Впервые работаю с Xpath, в принципе впервые пытаюсь спарсить какие то данные.
[image: Код]

Мне нужен класс price, чтобы вытянть нижний ценник (500р), что такое верхний ценник я не знаю, но если я в парсер ввожу только

//*[@id="main_container"]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOwqm.png)/div[2]/div[3]

то он в одну строчку вписывает оба ценника, а мне нужен только один.
Id=uCat_prev_price_78 - последнее число у всех товаров разная, не подойдет
Помогите достичь результата.

Крайне извиняюсь если вопрос будет не понятен или элементарен, не имею опыта общения на подобных форумах

Comment: `//div[starts-with(@id, "uCat_item_price_")]`

Comment: Не работает, увы

Comment: (только сейчас заметил у себя опечатку, вместо `//div` очевидно надо `//span`)

Comment: уже сам допер) спасибо